# When do we use "an analogy", "a metaphor" and "a figure of speech"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I have difficulty understanding when we use "an analogy", "a metaphor" and "a figure of speech".

I feel like in a casual conversation, people just use any of these words to say something that is different from its normal use.

Does a native English speaker distinguish the difference between them in a casual conversation?.

Is it correct to say:

"*I am like a bee in a bottle is an analogy*"

or

"*I am like a bee in a bottle is a metaphor*"

or

"*I am like a bee in a bottle is a figure of speech*"

Comment: The "casual native English speaker" will distinguish between *I'm **like** a bee in a bottle* and *I **am** a bee in a bottle* because one of the few things English teachers teach the natives is it's a ***simile*** if it includes the word ***like*** or similar, otherwise it's a ***metaphor***. But they won't be able to tell you why that's a useful distinction (because it isn't), and mostly they won't be consciously aware of the stark reality that ***all language is metaphor***.

Comment: I've downvoted, Tom, because I would like you to consider the implications of the phrase "casual native English speaker". Isn't that like asking about "sloppy painters"?  Is your question about colloquial usage or "proper" usage?

Comment: @TimR, I mean "an average native English speaker in a casual conversation"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between an analogy and a metaphor?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94703/the-difference-between-an-analogy-and-a-metaphor)

Comment: @Tom The average American speaker doesn't know the difference.  Your phrase could have meant "Do speakers who know the difference use the terms interchangeably when speaking casually?" I've removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Analogies and metaphors are figures of speech, of the sort of figure of speech called "tropes". ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech))

Analogy is a process involved in the making of certain figures of speech. For instance, parables and metaphors both involve analogy, as does the figure of speech called analogy, of course, this fact being somewhat of a truism.

- *I am like a bee in a bottle*: analogy
- *Bee in a bottle I blunt my mind vainly tackling problem after problem*: metaphor

*An educated guess on my part*

An average speaker knows what is an analogy and uses it without problems. He/she might not always be able to relate it precisely to the terms "metaphor" and "figure of speech".